# Importing the channel module from Tokio Core fails

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Inside a lib.rs I have this:

```
extern crate tokio_core;
use tokio_core::channel::{channel, Sender, Receiver};
```

Which ends up with this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `tokio_core::channel`
 --> src/main.rs:2:17
  |
2 | use tokio_core::channel::{channel, Sender, Receiver};
  |                 ^^^^^^^ Could not find `channel` in `tokio_core`
```

Looking at the [tokio_core crate's lib.rs file](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio-core/blob/8cd731fe469166dfba316a67987532b77d8dcea4/src/lib.rs#L118-L119), it exports `channel` as such:

```
#[doc(hidden)]
pub mod channel;
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this doesn't work.  I've tried this on both Rust 1.29 and 1.30.1.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the top of [channel.rs](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio-core/blob/8cd731fe469166dfba316a67987532b77d8dcea4/src/channel.rs#L6-L8), you'll see that the entire module is deprecated and is only available if you add the appropriate feature:

```
#![deprecated(since = "0.1.1", note = "use `futures::sync::mpsc` instead")]
#![allow(deprecated)]
#![cfg(feature = "with-deprecated")]
```

However, the Cargo.toml does not even allow for this feature to be enabled, and it [apparently **never** did](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio-core/commit/89fcc96dd44bff0ba85432d96a3a8f5b20adc94e). Indeed, the *entire crate* is now deprecated:

> ## Deprecation notice.
>
> This crate is scheduled for deprecation in favor of
>   [tokio](http://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio).
>
> `tokio-core` is still actively maintained, but only bug fixes will be
>   applied. All new feature development is happening in
>   [tokio](http://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio).

As mentioned in the deprecation notice, use [`futures::sync::mpsc::channel`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) instead.

Comment: Wow. I didn't see this deprecation notice at all. Nice to see the consolidation of all these separate tokio-* crates, though.

Comment: @GregMelton like many bigger projects, there still will be multiple crates. The big façade is for end users, the smaller crates are aimed at reusable libraries.